# Issues adding mail addresses to E-Mail desktop applications

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

Recently I was asked to setup a new Laptop for someone and it went fine for the most part, but when I installed Outlook I was having issues adding in new mail addresses. When asked for credentials to validate the account I typed in the data, it was accepted successfully, but immediately after the window to validate the credentials pops up again and again and the process of adding the new mail address wont go though. There are no error messages, just the window popping up again and again.

I also tried installing Mozilla Thunderbird to test if this is an direct issue with Outlook, but I had the same problems there. It does not seem to be an issue with the firewall and it worked previously with a different PC, so probably not an issue with the wifi network blocking anything. What else could be the cause? I'm kinda running out of ideas.

Comment: Are you looking for the Outlook 365 Autocomplete location to move to the new computer?  I am not certain from your question.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-copy-the-auto-complete-list-to-another-computer-83558574-20dc-4c94-a531-25a42ec8e8f0

Comment: Also look in Control Panel, Mail, and use the Email Accounts button to add email Accounts and proper addressing.

Comment: Any updates on your issue? Have your issue been resolved yet?

Comment: The issue has not been resolved yet. There are multiple types of mail accounts I am trying to add (Google mail etc) and the problem is not that the window asking for the credentials is popping up again and again, but rather [this window](https://imgur.com/a/XPhwT5a). So unfortunately the troubleshooting for on the support page has not been helpful yet.

Comment: POP and IMAP are enabled on all accounts as well, so that is not the issue either

Comment: You'd better raise a ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your mail account?

Have you tried to ticked the "Remember my credentials" button?
[image]

Here's are some troubleshooting steps for your reference: [Why does Outlook keep prompting for password](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook)